# How to handle query errors in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a simple question.

I am working on Zend framework 2.
I am trying to make an AJAX call to fetch all booking data from table `booking` by passing the booking_id. Trouble is, the query is failing for reasons unknown. The actual query is complex and its working when I replace $booking_id with an actual booking_id like '22432'. Hence, I believe that the query is fine, there is some other issue.

But I don't know how to fetch the query errors/exceptions in an Ajax call. Can someone help me with this?

Javascript:

```
$.post("dashboard/getBookingDataByBookingId", {
        booking_id: bookingId,
    },
    function(data){
        if(data.response == true) {
         alert(data);
        } else {
         alert('failed');
        }
    }, 'json');
```

Controller

```
public function getBookingDataByBookingIdAction()
{
  $request = $this->getRequest();
  $response = $this->getResponse();
  if ($request->isPost()) 
  {
    $post_data = $request->getPost();
    $booking_id = $post_data['booking_id'];
    $booking_data = array();
    $booking_data = $this->getBookingTable()->getBookingByUserIdAndBookingId($booking_id);
    if (!$booking_data)
      $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('response' => false, 'booking_data' => $booking_data)));
    else {
      $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('response' => true, 'booking_data' => $booking_data)));
    }
  }
  return $response;
}
```

The bookingTable model has a public function:

```
public function getBookingByUserIdAndBookingId($booking_id)
{
   $sql = "Select * from booking where id='".$booking_id."';
   try {
        $statement = $this->adapter->query($sql);
        $res =  $statement->execute();    
        return $res->current();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return $ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are posting a variable named 'id':

```
{
    id: bookingId,
}
```

So you should access it as:

```
$post_data = $request->getPost();
$booking_id = $post_data['id'];
```

or more concisely:

```
$booking_id = $request->getPost('id');
```

You should also be using parameterised queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo while asking the question. Have made the edit in the question.

Comment: If it works when you hardcode the id into the query, something like this is still the most likely cause of your error. I'd suggest you try and debug it a little to see if `$booking_id` has a value inside the `getBookingByUserIdAndBookingId()` function.

Comment: Did that but to no avail. Double checked the variable titles etc. Will be great to find out whats going on at the query level via catching exceptions.

Comment: Here is another interesting insight:

If I hardcode the booking_id in $.post call, everything works.
But if I let the booking_id be fetched via onclick, the call fails. Although, I checked by putting breakpoints that even via onclick method, the correct booking_id is fetched.

Any ideas on why such weird behavior?

Comment: If it works when you hardcode the value into the JS, this isn't a PHP problem at all. Can you post more of the javascript code? Where is `bookingId` set?

Answer (score 0):

For Getting errors/exceptions in an Ajax call use:

In Google Chrome use: **POSTMAN** Extension

In FireFox user: **FIREBUG** Plugin